# Tesseract Android tools Crash Error

Tags: android, tesseract

I'm having a crash error on init method in `TessBaseAPI` class, please help me on this one, below is the log file:

```
D/dalvikvm(26619): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.appname.../lib/liblept.so 0x40513f58
D/dalvikvm(26619): Added shared lib /data/data/com.appname.../lib/liblept.so 0x40513f58
D/dalvikvm(26619): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.appname...t/lib/libtess.so 0x40513f58
D/dalvikvm(26619): Added shared lib /data/data/com.appname.../lib/libtess.so 0x40513f58
V/Tesseract(native)(26619): Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClassInit
V/Tesseract(native)(26619): Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeConstruct
V/Tesseract(native)(26619): Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeInit
I/Tesseract(native)(26619): Attempting Init() with dir=/mnt/sdcard/tessdata/, lang=eng
I/ActivityManager(  107): Process com.appname....tesseract (pid 26619) has died.
```

Comment: Do you have the required *.traineddata language data files in /mnt/sdcard/tessdata/ directory?

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the wrong version of language data file.

See my comment here -

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/issues/detail?id=3

There are also two versions of **eng.traineddata** file attached to the bug report. You need the smaller of the two for Tesseract Android Tools. Bigger one is for the recent version of Tesseract